# Castle Windsor to create instance of object based on URL parameters?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Is it possible for me to get Castle Windsor to inject an object that has been created with URL parameters? Either as query string parameters or parameters defined in a routing configuration?

Currently this object is being passed in to the Controller's Index action method, but I need to have it available in the constructor.

If so, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario sounds really hacky, but if you really wanted to do this I would recommend implementing a custom controller factory.

There, you can control the instantiation of your controllers.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by [looking at the documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Passing-Arguments.ashx).